# Answer your own question - share your knowledge gets downvotes

Tags: support, specific-question, instant-self-answer

I recently noticed this option "Answer your own question". It says **share your knowledge !**

[image]

A little read [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) helped me understand that

- if you have a question that you already know the answer to
- if you’d like to document it in public so others (including yourself) can find it later
- it is OK to ask, and answer, your own question on a relevant Stack Exchange site.

> To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own
> question, **it is explicitly encouraged**

So I went ahead an created a Q&A on something I didnt find on stackoverflow.com which I thought would be useful to some one in future.

Here is what I created

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302688/how-to-use-jqplot-with-asp-net-mvc

But soon after I created this, I got downvotes.

Can someone help me understand what exactly is this for ? I have alerted moderators too for this but to no avail.

Have I mis-understood this ? Please can some one help me understand this.

Comment: cmon ! this is the last place I can come to with such queries on discussing features of stackoverflow, and here too I get downvotes ? sad real sad :(

Comment: meta downvotes - [we don't agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: [Votes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Your question is not a practical, answerable question as questions asked on Stack Overflow should be. See [Direct answer of own question lead to immediate close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137054/direct-answer-of-own-question-lead-to-immediate-close) and [When should I post a question with the answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136617/when-should-i-post-a-question-with-the-answer)

Comment: Answering your own question is fine (note that no one downvoted the _answer_), but that doesn't mean that the _question_ is a good one.

Comment: this all is so wrong :(

Comment: Note that the downvotes were on your question, not the answer. That should hint that the problem was with your question and has nothing to do with who posted the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even when you self-answer a question, the question and answer are evaluated by users **entirely independently of each other**.  If the question is a good question, it's likely to get upvotes, and if it's not it will get downvotes.  The answer, on the other hand, is again evaluated in a vacuum; if it's a good answer it will tend to get upvotes, and if not you'll see downvotes.  The fact that you authored both doesn't change that.

Imagine, for a second, that someone would have posted the question you posted, without an answer, and you came across it.  What would you have done?  How would you respond?  That's what people did when they saw your question; they noticed a very poor question and downvoted accordingly.

For a question to be good on Stack Overflow it needs to be specific rather than overly broad, it needs to have a narrow enough scope that it can be answered in a few paragraphs as opposed to asking a question that takes a book to answer, it needs to be concrete enough that the answer will be evaluated based on facts, rather than a subjective basis, etc.

Answer (score 15):

> How to use Jqplot with ASP.NET MVC ?
>
> Can I get a step by step detailed guide to using JqPlot with ASP.NET MVC ?

Is not a real question, and I have closed it as such:

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is **ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad**, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.

Emphasis mine.

The self-answer feature is not some kind of golden ticket for you to post questions that are immune to getting downvoted and closed. You need to ensure your **question** is a good fit for our standards, not just your **answer**, even if you have the answer to your own question. Otherwise your question is going to get downvoted, closed and deleted, just like any other poor question on the site, and your answer won't be spared either meaning all your effort would have gone down the drain.

In this case your two-line question doesn't give anybody much to go on, while your answer has become a full-blown step by step tutorial that doesn't actually answer any specific question. It could even have qualified as "not an answer" in that respect. But my point is that had anybody else posted that answer, your question would still be closed because there are issues with your question, and not so with the answer.

By the way, moderators can't do anything about your questions getting downvoted, so I declined your flags as well. The one in the best position to do something about that, is you, the question asker.

See also:

- [What can be done to improve moderation of self-answered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137353/what-can-be-done-to-improve-moderation-of-self-answered-questions)
- [Is Stack Overflow a central store for tutorials?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134645/is-stack-overflow-a-central-store-for-tutorials)

Comment: why do you think so ? what's not real about it ?

Comment: If you were to ask it as a question, without knowing the answer, it would have been closed as well. This is not the kind of practical problem you face, which is acceptable for SO.

Comment: waat ? really ? and my this question here on meta is also not fit ?

Comment: Once again, downvotes on Meta are different. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: `reasonably answered in its current form.` FYI I have given an answer

Comment: @Yasser And no one downvoted your answer. That doesn't really mean the question isn't _extremely_ poor though.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Actually, it's sitting at +1/-1 right now.

Comment: @animuson Well, Meta can be a harsh mistress sometimes...

Comment: Ok I understand everything BUT why did this question got downvoted ?

Comment: You obviously do not understand if you ask that

Comment: @juan that is, why he asked!

Answer (score 7):

Your question, as stated, is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Yes, you are encouraged to share your knowledge, but your question still needs to meet the Stack Overflow quality standards.

Your question does not state a practical problem with the jqPlot library. Instead, it asks a open-ended, vague question on how to use it.

Had you instead posted your attempts to work with jqPlot so far, with a particular point you were having trouble with, then your question would have been much more acceptable. A self-answer to such a question is certainly very welcome.